# Image Remote Upload Script

Tags: php

I'm having trouble to make a php file that'll be able to copy remote images and save it to a directory.

so i'm going to input a set of image urls into the first text box, and when run the image will grab those images and save them to a specified directory and display the new set of urls. :)

How can i do that?

Comment: BTW, i do not know anything about PHP, how will i insert those codes?

Comment: Ok, then check the faq on stackoverflow or search for "PHP Tutorial"

Comment: That is an insecure practice, one could easuly drop code into the image to make it act as a php,jsp,js, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Place this code in your script.php

```
<?php
$image = 'http://remote.com/image.jpeg';
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.basename($image), file_get_contents('http://remote.com/image.jpeg'));
```

Comment: BTW, i do not know anything about PHP, how will i insert those codes? I wanted to use it so i can access the script by accesing http://site.xx/script.php

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) along with the [`fopen()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [`fwrite()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php), and [`fclose()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) gang.

```
<?php
foreach( $_POST['image'] as $image ) {
    $f = fopen( "/path/to/image/folder/".basename( $image ) ); //Open image file
    fwrite( $f, file_get_contents( $image ) ); //Write the contents of the web image to the newly created image on your server
    fclose( $f ); //Close the file
}
?>
```

Comment: BTW, i do not know anything about PHP, how will i insert those codes? I wanted to use it so i can access the script by accesing http://site.xx/script.php

Answer (score 0):

This should start you off

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo file_get_contents("http://www.somewebsite.com/images/image.jpg");
```

You could then save this file to a local directory